# Retrieve the data type of a query/table field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that converts user input into a WHERE statement which is applied as a filter to the form.

I'm trying to improve the logic that determines whether the input should be enclosed in quotes or not:

[Zip] = '01234' NOT [Zip] = 1234

[Active] = Yes NOT [Active] = 'Yes'

My preferred solution is to examine the user input and the field data type, and determine the correct course from there.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the field data type.

I was expecting QueryDefs(QueryName).Fields(FieldName).Type and TableDefs(TableName).Fields(FieldName).Type to return an integer corresponding to the type: 8 for String, 2 for integer, 11 for boolean, etc. But instead, it returns 10 (vbError) for everything.

I considered using VarType([FieldName]), but that returns the data type for the first record. If the field value for the first record happens to be empty, it returns Null, not the data type for the field.

What's the right function or property to use to get the data type for a query/table field?

Comment: For a DAO field, `Type` returns values from the [DAO.DataTypeEnum enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/datatypeenum-enumeration-dao)  The value 10 is `dbText`, not an error condition.

Comment: Works for me: `CurrentDb.TableDefs("Holidays").Fields("HolName").type`. Returns 4 for number, 8 for date, 10 for short text, 12 for long text.

Comment: @HansUp - I was incorrectly looking at the returns for VarType, where 10 is vbError. Thanks!